# UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum doesn't report error when disk is full

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera-roll

When trying to save a video to the camera roll/photo album using

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum
```

and the disk storage is full, there is no error in the call to the completion callback method

```
- (void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;
```

The only indication of the disk being full and the copy didn't work is that the video isn't there in the Camera roll afterwards.

Just wanted to check if someone else has got this to actually work or if this is a bug.